# Neither $L^1\mathbb {(R)}$ or $L^2\mathbb {(R)}$ is contained in the other

Tags: real-analysis

I have difficulty in proving that

> neither $L^1\mathbb{(R)}$ or $L^2\mathbb{(R)}$ is contained in the other

Does anyone know of a nice way to show this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $R=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ gives one direction.

Comment: I guess you mean $R=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @DanielXiang Although for $R=[0,1]$ the other inclusion is actually true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $$x^{-1/2}\cdot \chi_{(0,1)}$$ is in $L^1\mathbb{(R)}$ but not in $L^2\mathbb{(R)}.$ The function $$x^{-1}\cdot \chi_{(1,\infty)}$$ is in $L^2\mathbb{(R)}$ but not in $L^1\mathbb{(R)}.$

Comment: Such a simple and elegant answer! Thank you a lot